# What is the probability that a white ball will be taken out in the nth step?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $k$ white balls and $j$ black balls in the box.There are enough white and black balls outside the box. In each step one ball is taken out(with return), then $m$ balls of the same colour are put in the box.What is the probability that a white ball will be taken out in the $n$th step?

I have tried to make recurrence formula but it got too complicated to get the result.

Comment: What is the probability that the second ball chosen is white?

Comment: P2=(k(k+m) + kj) / ((k+j)(k+j+m))

Comment: Is this ok? Pn=(k...(k+(n-1)m) +...+  kj^n-1) / ((k+j)...(k+j+(n-1)m))

Comment: @Ggi88 yes for the second ball what you wrote, now take $k$ out of the numerator and simplify that. What do you get?

Comment: Ignore the Pn, focus on what you wrote for the second ball.

Comment: Than pn=k/(k+j) for every n?